# Changing System Account of Central Admin on MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, central-administration, user-accounts

I've been trying to change the System Account used on my MOSS 2007 with Sharepoint 3.0 Central Admin. I've followed the instruction on this [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838) as instructed but the Central Admin, when opened, still uses the old System Account that I want to replace.

The user accounts I'm using a both local users and I've added the new user account to the same groups as the first user that is the System Account of Central Admin. I've also made the new user account a dbadmin in my SQL Server 2008 R2.

Am I still missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that you have done this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838/en-gb

but have you also done an IISreset?

All the machines on the farm would also need to change and once that is complete top it off with an IISreset

When you make the change you can verify it by going to services, sort until you see Microsoft  SharePoint and then look at the users ID running the service.

One very important thing, make sure the new user has the correct rights in SQL server, you should also make the new user the owner over the associated DBs.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll go over my settings again to check if I missed something.